# 12.10 - GPU lockup

Tags: 12.10, freeze, gpu, lockup

I just downloaded the Ubuntu 12.10 and i am trying to install on my laptop with Nvidia 
chipset, on previous version i was able to install on through nomodeset command and the i use to install later on .. the last i used was on ubuntu 11.

and now i am stuck with ubuntu 12.10 hanging on primary boot.. with GPU lockup error and i know its the graphic card bug. but every through grub when i go in failsafe x option, system just sits there and its stuck..

Please help for this one.